Is 3, 3 satisfiability trivial after all?
Tovey's paper from 1982 clearly states that:

Theorem 2.1. Boolean satisfiability is NP-complete when restricted to instances
with 2 or 3 variables per clause and at most 3 occurrences per variable.

Throughout the paper, he refers to a r,s-SAT formula as such:

Let r,s-SAT denote the class of instances with exactly r variables per
clause and at most s occurrences per variable.

So by 3, 3-SAT, following the author's logic, I understand an instance that has exactly 3 variables per clause and variables appear at most 3 times in the entire given formula.
Furthermore, Tovey says that 3, 3-SAT is in fact trivial, and that

Theorem 2.4. Every instance of r,r-SAT is satisfiable

So obviously 3, 3-SAT is no exception to his Theorem 2.4.
What I don't understand though, if it was established in Theorem 2.1 that a boolean CNF expression made up of clauses with 2 or 3 variables is NP-complete, then why by say if there is a generalized clause with 2 variables present like:
A or B  using his transformation or polynomial reduction used in proving Theorem 2.1 a clause with 2 literals could look like this: not(xi) or xi+1
I will refer to an instance formula of Theorem 2.1 as F from now on.
Why can't we create a new formula F' (from F) so that whenever we encounter such a clause like the one above:

Remove the 2 literal clause cj, say cj = A or B
Add for each clause cj removed a dummy variable, say dj in the new 2 clauses:

A or B or dj
A or B or not(dj)



And the resulting F' boolean formula is obviously 3, 3-SAT.
Yet, from the transformation above it is obvious by rules of inference (A or B must be True as well if (A or B or dj) and (A or B or not(dj)) are True).
So, to me it seems that F is True whenever F' is True (and vice versa).
Therefore, the polynomial time reduction presented above would appear to be valid.
It resulted that any F formula that is Theorem 2.1 compliant (the problem being NP-complete) could be reduced to F', which is an instance of 3,3-SAT.
So why then 3,3-SAT isn't NP-complete?


And the resulting F' boolean formula is obviously 3, 3-SAT.

This is not true: by duplicating the literals $A$ and $B$, you may have too many occurences of some variable. E.g. your translation of
$$(x\vee y)\wedge (x\vee y\vee u)\wedge (x\vee y\vee v)$$ would yield $$(x\vee y\vee a)\wedge (x\vee y\vee\neg a)\wedge (x\vee y\vee u)\wedge (x\vee y\vee v),$$ but that has too many $x$s and $y$s.

Thanks! I didn't realize the pair of variables x, y could each appear 4 times but that makes sense. I wonder if the polynomial reduction would be valid for 3, 4-SAT though (3, 4-SAT is known to be NP-complete)

@nonsensicalworld Nope - consider e.g. $(x\vee y_1)\wedge (x\vee y_2)\wedge (x\vee y_3)\wedge [stuff]$. The reduction only works to 3,6-SAT since in general the number of occurrences of each variable can double.
